# WiFi is connected but internet not working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet

I have a lenovo x230 running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've been using it just fine for a while, but all of a sudden the internet's stopped working. It's connected to the router just fine (I can see the antenna bars saying it's connected) but when I try to go to a webpage, it's just loading forever. I've tried the fix listed here

(http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985079)

but it hasn't done anything (the instructions are a little confusing though). I'm booting Windows 7 right now and the internet works just fine when I'm on Windows, so I know it must be a problem with Ubuntu. I haven't touched any network settings before this problem happened, and I've been using it just fine for months, so I don't know why I'm getting this problem all of a sudden.

Oh and I haven't updated anything in a few weeks (you know when the update manager pops up every so often listing all the things there's an update for) so I know it's not some update that broke it.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and type these commands separately: `ifconfig`, `route -n`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`, and `ping -c 4 google.com`. Copy their outputs and paste them in your question.

Comment: I put my results in a gist because they're a little long. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c001b8ac5a7369d46cfc

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I would also like to see: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: it just displayed my network card model, intel centrino advanced n 6205 (i saved the exact output in a txt file then rebooted to windows, but something's wrong with the file. It just printed out the one line with my network card name though).

Comment: At the end of that line, there's a `[ven_id#:dev_id#]`, I guess that's what he wanted to see =).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (I have the same laptop):

```
sudo rmmod iwldvm
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
sudo modprobe iwldvm
```

Now, this only worked for me. I don't actually know what this code does, so use at your own risk.